# Create a list from SQL database using HTML/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

Im trying to create a drop down list/menu of users from my SQL database table. Could anyone help me with the code please? The code below is just for a normal list with options 1 & 2. How do i make the list retrieve all the items in a specific table using html/php/sql. Sorry im not very experienced with this, thanks in advance.

```
<select name="user" id="user">
<option value="a" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="b">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

there are several ways but i'll show mine

First, take the data you want to retrieve from query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name, id FROM users");
```

Then echo a select followed by a while cycle to iterate the various options:

```
<?php
echo "<select name='user'>";
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
    echo "<option value='".$temp['id']."'>".$temp['name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

The result should be:

```
<select name="user">
   <option value='1'>User name 1</option>
   <option value='2'>User name 2</option>
</select>
```

Hope this was useful for you :)

Comment: I hope you'd escape your HTML output if you were doing this for real.

Comment: you mean unescape? it should be like this:

<?php
echo "<select name='user'>";
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
    echo "<option value='".stripslashes($temp['id'])."'>".stripslashes($temp['name'])."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

Comment: No I mean something like echo "<option value='".htmlspecialchars($temp['id'])."'>".htmlspecialchars ($temp['name'])."</option>". Otherwise it's a potential HTML/Javascript injection security hole.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Dynamic Drop-down](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-software/php-dynamic-drop-down.file)